# how to pass json object into javascript function in php

Tags: javascript, php, json

i have a json object.
**$json = json_decode($data,true);**
it looks like-

```
array(5) {
  ["screenShareCode"]=>
  string(9) "021113322"
  ["appletHtml"]=>
  string(668) ""
  ["presenterParams"]=>
  string(396) "aUsEN5gBYi4vlIEGpk0="
  ["viewerUrl"]=>
  string(65) "http://api.leap.com/v2/viewer/021113322?accountid=mynet"
  ["origin"]=>
  string(3) "API"
}
```

```
    alert('?php echo $json; ?>');
```

when i am trying to assign this into javascript variable it gives me an error saying "**unterminated string constant**".

Comment: `alert('?php echo $data; ?>');` The `$json` variable is decoded. You need the json encoded value.

Comment: alert() having '<' missing..

Comment: Try exactly like `var obj = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't decode it, in PHP *or* JavaScript. The contents of a JSON string is a valid JavaScript literal.

```
<?php
 ...
?>
<script ...>
var data=<?php echo $data; ?>;
alert(data["screenShareCode"]);
<?php
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alert(<?php echo json_encode($json); ?>);
```

or:

```
alert(<?php echo $data; ?>);
```

You're a bit confused about terminology. `$data` is a JSON string, `$json` is a PHP array that you got by decoding the JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. I have created a php file named sample.php. We have a php array named $data. Encode that data in to json using `json_endode()`. That results json formatted data. Then we can assign it into a java script variable like  `var jsonData = <?php echo $jsonData ?>;` Note that this is done inside `<script>` tag.

```
<?php
// We have some data
$data = array(
    "screenShareCode"=>"021113322",
    "appletHtml"=>"",
    "presenterParams"=>"aUsEN5gBYi4vlIEGpk0",
    "viewerUrl"=>"http://api.screenleap.com/v2/viewer/021113322?accountid=mynet",
    "origin"=>"API"
);
// Convert it into json format.
$jsonData = json_encode($data,true);
?>

<script>
// Assign that json data to a java-script variable
var jsonData = <?php echo $jsonData ?>;

// To view the full data 
console.log(jsonData);

// You can take a specific data like this.
alert(jsonData.presenterParams);
</script>
```